# npm ERR! could not determine executable to run. Even when I have reinstalled node

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code, npm

I'm a new react user, so this is the first time I installed react. When I was creating a new  project I got an error which is

> npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

I have tried to reinstall all node js related software but nothing worked.

Environment Variable:

[image]

Logs:

```
1 info using npm@9.7.2
2 info using node@v18.16.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:V:\Business\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\nevyl\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 10ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 10ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
21 verbose title npm exec create-react app .
22 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create-react" "app" "."
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-25T10_09_15_970Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-25T10_09_15_970Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 11ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 57ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile done cleaning log files
33 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 573ms (cache miss)
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react 1091ms (cache miss)
35 timing command:exec Completed in 1151ms
36 verbose stack Error: could not determine executable to run
36 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\get-bin-from-manifest.js:17:23)
36 verbose stack     at exec (C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:188:15)
36 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js:61:5)
37 verbose pkgid create-react@0.0.0
38 verbose cwd V:\Business
39 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.23486
40 verbose node v18.16.1
41 verbose npm  v9.7.2
42 error could not determine executable to run
43 verbose exit 1
44 timing npm Completed in 1542ms
45 verbose code 1
46 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-25T10_09_15_970Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the correct directory? I usually get this error when I'm outside the designated directory. Try using `cd` to get into the directory.

If that doesn't work, try checking your `scripts` into the `package.json`

Comment: I set it to V:\Business folder using "npx create-react app . ". I forgot to mention that I set this in windows so most websites I have researched before is not relevant as most of them gave me the solution for linux or mac.

For the package.json file idk which code to be checked. ummm just to be sure is that in this directory C:\Users\nevyl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm ?

Comment: That is the wrong command. You should use ```npx create-react-app my-project```. Here my-project is the project name. If you want your project to be in the same folder then you can input ```npx create-react-app ./```

Comment: Since you weren't able to create a react project, the ```package.json``` won't exist

Comment: And check if you installed NodeJS globally. Try checking online how to check if NodeJS exists on your PC using the ```cmd```.

Answer (score 0):

try going in the root of your entire project. I just did that and it worked fine. also make sure you're using the correct version of node/npm. consider getting node version manager to quickly change

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35136692)